# Finding values for integral $\iint_A \frac{dxdy}{|x|^p+|y|^q}$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Given the following integral
$$\iint_A \frac{dxdy}{|x|^p+|y|^q}$$
where $A=|x|+|y|>1$. How can one find for which $p$ and $q$ values the integral converges?

Since the function is  non-negative it is sufficient to show convergence/divergence on any Jordan exhaustion of $A$ in order to show convergence/divergence on $A$. 
I tried to use polar coordinates here, but I don't know how to fit it to match $p$ and $q$ so it'll actually be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Polar coordinates seem like they might be a good starting point.

Comment: What does $R$ mean?

Comment: Are you sure that $A= \mathbb{R}^2$ and not where $|x| + |y| \geq 1$ ??

Comment: sorry for the typo, fixed..

Comment: ok I haven't totally figured it out yet but my idea is to take a Jordan exhaustion of parallelograms bounded between $y=-x+1$ and $y=-x+j$ for $j=1,2,....$, and after changing to polar representation - the radius is bounded between $ \frac{ \sqrt{2} }{2 \cos \theta}$ (not really sure about that) and $j$ and the angle between $0$ and $\frac{ \pi }{2} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to observe $x, y > 0$ (from symmetry) and instead of $x+y\geq 1$ take $\max(x,y)\geq 1$ - since we only got rid of a finite integral it doesn't change the convergence.

Substituting $\phi(x,y) = (u, v) = (x^p, y^q)$ gives
$$ J_\phi = \det \frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)} = \frac{1}{\det\frac{d(u,v)}{d(x,y)}} = \frac{1}{pq\cdot u^a \cdot s^b} $$
where $a = \frac{p-1}{p}= 1- \frac{1}{p}, b = \frac{q-1}{q}= 1-\frac{1}{q}$.

Now:

$$\int_{min(x,y) \geq 1} \frac{dx \, dy}{x^p+y^q}= \frac{1}{pq}[\int_{u\geq s\geq 1} \frac{du \, ds}{(u+s)\cdot u^a \cdot s^b} + \int_{s > u \geq 1} \dots]$$

Observe the first integrand ($u\geq s$) - it converges and diverges the same as $$\int_{u\geq max(1,s)} \frac {du \, ds}{2u \cdot u^a\cdot s^b} = \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{u}\frac{ds \, du}{2u^{a+1}\cdot s^b} = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{u^{b-1}}-1}{2u^{a+1}(1-b)}\,du$$

So for them to converge we need $a+1+b-1 > 1 \implies \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} < 1$, and also $a+1 > 1\implies \frac{1}{p}<1$, and if we'll take the second integrand instead we get $b+1 > 1 \implies \frac{1}{q} < 1$ so overall we just need $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} < 1 \, \cap \,max(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q}) < 1$.

Comment: why do we need a+1>1?

Comment: So after you "open the brackets"  both $\int \frac{1}{2u^{a+b}}$ and $\int \frac{1}{2u^{a+1}}$ will converge