# For what values of $p,q$ ${\iint}_{|x|+|y|\ge 1}{1\over |x|^p+|y|^q}dxdy$ does the integral converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

For what values of $p,q$
$${\iint}_{|x|+|y|\ge 1}{1\over |x|^p+|y|^q}dxdy$$
does integral converge?

I thought of claiming that it is enough to show what values it converges for in the first quarter ($x,y\ge 0$), but in the integration I run into a problem; Suppose $y$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$. Then $x$ has to go from $1-y$ to $\infty$ and vice verse. Which means I am exceeding the boundaries I set as soon as $y>1$. I then thought that $x$ should go from $\max (0,1-y)$ to $\infty$, but I don't know how I feel about using the maximum function. If none of the option is legitimate, is there another way to use the first quarter, and if there isn't- how can I know whether or not using the first quarter is sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry
$$\iint_{|x|+|y|\ge 1}{1\over |x|^p+|y|^q}\,dxdy =
4\iint_{x+y\ge 1,x\ge 0,y\ge0}{1\over x^p+y^q}\,dxdy =
4\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=1-x}^\infty\cdots + 4\int_{x=1}^\infty\int_{y=0}^\infty\cdots
$$

Comment: how do you go on from there?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1668759/124982